# SSRS number format expression showing unexpected results

Tags: reporting-services

I have a table that contains metric data for various business units in our organization. There is one column that contains the KPI measurments. I've created a report to display each business units KPI's. Some of the metrics need to be displayed as whole numbers, others need to be displayed as percentages.

I created an expression to handle the multiple formats. The problem I'm having is with the percentages. For example one of the numbers (which should be displayed as 93.74%) appears as 939474%. If I remove the expression and set the format to percentage using the text box properties, the number displays as 93.74%.

Here is the expression I'm using:
    = IIF(Fields!KPI_desc.Value like "*Rate",
    Format(Fields!Value.Value,"0.00%"),"0")

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: What textbox format are using for the cell normally?

Comment: Don't follow the question. I right clicked on the text box, clicked text box properties then clicked number. Without any expression being added, the Category that is highlighted is 'Default'. If I change that to Percentage, the values for what I want to be percentages are correct. However, since I don't want ALL values to be listed as %, I  clicked on Custom and then added the expression above.

Comment: I think I got this to work. Don't know if it's the 'correct' solution but I removed the Format(Fields!Value.Value from the expression and it returned the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you put this into the Format Expression so that it will return the result like integer. Actually you just need to put this expression into textbox directly.

= IIF(Fields!KPI_desc.Value like "*Rate", FormatPercent(Fields!Value.Value,2),"0")